# 17th or 18th century use of the continued fraction expansion of $(1 + \sqrt D)/2$ to solve the diophantine equation $x^2 - D y^2 = 4$

Tags: mathematics, euler, fermat

Can someone please provide an early reference to the use of the continued fraction expansion of $\frac{1+\sqrt D}2$ to solve the Diophantine equation $x^2 - D y^2 = 4$ for a positive integer $D$ congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, $D$ not a square?  Or some method equivalent to the use of the continued fraction expansion of $\frac{1+\sqrt D}2$.  An 18<sup>th</sup> century reference?  17<sup>th</sup> century?  Modern references are easy to find—20<sup>th</sup> and 21<sup>st</sup> century.

An equivalent method might involve use of binary quadratic forms, even if the terminology “binary quadratic form” is not used.  For example Brouncker's (maybe it's Wallis') method for solving $x^2 - D y^2 = 1$ (see André Weil, *Number Theory, An approach through history from Hammurapi to Legendre*, Birkhäuser, 2001, pp. 92 ff) essentially uses binary quadratic forms and is equivalent to computing the continued fraction of $\sqrt D$.

I have been searching for a source for this for a few weeks, and have not found anything.  I've looked at Weil, Edwards, Mollin, Jacobson and Williams, Dickson's History (especially Vol II, pp. 351 to 353), Whitford, Fermat's Oeuvres (but I haven't read every page!), Lenstra's 2002 Notices article, Williams's millennial talk, Mahoney, Ribenboim, countless websites, and more.

Comment: For what it's worth, on page 11 of Conrad's [Pell’s Equation, II](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) he credits Lagrange with the reductive technique for solving the generalized Pell's equation that "*can be settled using the continued fraction of $\sqrt d$*."

Comment: The Fermat/Brouncker/Wallis method for solving Pell equations in 1657 is essentially based on the regular continued fraction of $\sqrt{D}$.  Lagrange (about 1770) is the first to show this method always works.  I am specifically interested in whether there are any references for use of $(1 + \sqrt{D})/2$ prior to the 20th century.  Actually, I think the earliest reference I have is 1954 (O. Perron's continued fractions book, third edition).  But, the method must pre-date this, whether or not it was proved to always work.